# Question about derivative and critical numbers

Tags: calculus

I am confused about the derivative and its critical numbers for a piece-wise function. For example,

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} x^4\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) & x \neq 0\\ 0 & x=0.\end{cases}$$

I know that the limit of the first part is $0$ and since $f(0)=0$, therefore this function is continuous at $x=0$. However, I am confused about how to determine if $0$ is a critical number. Let's say, if I take the derivative of the first part, then $0$ will be a critical number because when $x=0$, the derivative of the first part does not exist. However, If I just simply take the derivative of the second part, then when $x=0$ the derivative of the second part is also equal to $0$. So, what exactly make $0$ a critical number. Also, I am wondering if I should only put $0$ into the derivative of the first part because second part is when $x=0$, and derivative is when $x$ approaches $0$.

Comment: "First part, second part"?  Can you clarify what each part is referring to?  If I have calculated correctly, $f'(0)=0$ as well...

Comment: first part is x^4sin(1/x) and second part is x=0, for the first part, dy/dx=4x^3sin(1/x)-x^2cos(1/x), when x=0, this derivative is not defined, right?

Comment: Taking the limit as $x\to 0$ I see two parts both approaching $0$, and it looks well-defined to me...

Comment: confused, could you explain why for the first part, derivative exists when x=0?

Comment: Stop using "first" and "second" parts...It's the definition for $\;x\neq 0\;$ and the one for $\;x=0\;$ .

Comment: OK, I think when x not equal to 0, the derivative of f(x) when x not equal to 0 is not defined at x=0.

Comment: It is: look at the answer given

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f'(0)\stackrel ?=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}x=\lim_{x\to 0} x^3\sin\frac1x=0\;\;\color{green}\checkmark$$

Comment: A much-simplified approach compared to what I tried...

Comment: @abiessu , you though proved $\;f'(x)\;$ is continuous at zero, much more than what was asked, so it is fair your approach is more complex...

Comment: Thank you, I understand it now.

Answer (score 1):

Using the example function

$$f(x)=x^4\sin\left(\frac 1x\right)$$

we have the derivative

$$f'(x)=4x^3\sin\left(\frac 1x\right)-x^2\cos\left(\frac 1x\right)$$

Consider the following limits:

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}4x^3\sin\left(\frac 1x\right)-x^2\cos\left(\frac 1x\right)$$

$$=\lim_{y\to +\infty}\frac 4{y^3}\sin y-\frac 1{y^2}\cos y\tag 1$$

$$\lim_{x\to 0^-}4x^3\sin\left(\frac 1x\right)-x^2\cos\left(\frac 1x\right)$$

$$=\lim_{y\to -\infty}\frac 4{y^3}\sin y-\frac 1{y^2}\cos y\tag 2$$

In both cases $(1)$ and $(2)$ we have a bounded function ($\sin y$ or $\cos y$) multiplied by a number rapidly approaching $0$, which always goes to $0$.